# Camel - how to change file permission on toD("file:~")

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I have route like below

```
fromF("file:~~")
....
.toD("file:someotherlocation/")
```

the file is initially owned by userA but it is changed to be owned by tomcat user(code is deployed on external tomcat).
Is there a way, either keep owner or provide proper permission for the group.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not possible to change owner, but with the newer Java versions there is a way to change the owner of the file. You can create a JIRA ticket at Apache Camel to ask for such a functionality.

However there is a `chmod` option on the file component to change permissions. See the Camel documentation for more details.